# Prove for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$ there are natural $t$ consecutive number such that every one of them are not power of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$ there are natural $t$ consecutive number such that every one of them are not power of primes.

$q$ will be Power of primes if $\exists p $ prime such that $q=p^t$ , $q,p,t \in \mathbb{N}$

> Hint (1): Chinese remainder theorem
>
> Hint (2): Solve. $n\equiv−1\pmod{2\times3}$ and  $n\equiv−2\pmod{5\times7}$

***Attempt:***
Solve the hint (2)

Chinese remainder theorem

$$M= 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 ...\cdot k...$$
$$M_1= 5\cdot 7$$
$$M_2 = 2\cdot 3$$
$$M_n = p_{k-1}\cdot p_k$$
$m_i$ , $M_i$ are coprime for all $i$ , Let $y_i$ be the inverse of $M_i$ mod $m_i$ .
$$n=\sum^{k}_{i=1}a_i\cdot M_i\cdot y_i$$

$$n=(-1)\cdot5\cdot7\cdot5+(-2)\cdot2\cdot3\cdot6=-247$$

$$n\equiv-247\pmod{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}$$
$$n\equiv 173\pmod{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}$$

Comment: Hint;  Solve, e.g., $n\equiv -1 \pmod {2\times 3}$ and $n\equiv -2\pmod {5\times 7}$.

Comment: I don't understand.  The problem in my hint is a (rather trivial) exercise in the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  The point was to spot the pattern in my construction in a way that lets you get $t$ non-prime powers in a row,

Comment: If you don't know what the Chinese remainder theorem says, or how to use it, then that's what you need to study.

Comment: @lulu I edit the post for your hint . I know what is Chinese remainder theorem I still dont get it

Comment: In $n!$ always there are at least two primes with exposant $1$ and these are the greatest prime factors of $n$. On the other hand  it is known that the integers between two consecutive primes can be arbitrarily large. I feel it cuold be a key to solve your problem

Comment: @Piquito Oh . can u give me a full proof for that say ? "In n! always there are at least two primes with exponent 1 " i tried to seek about this proof and I didn't see noting its may can be a key .

Comment: Please solve the problem I gave in my hint.  That should give you two consecutive integers, one of which is divisible by $6$ and the other is divisible by $35$.  Neither of those can be a prime power.  Now use the same construction I gave to get three consecutive non prime powers, and so on.

Comment: @Emily.d lulu's construction which can be extended to an arbitary number of congruences ensures that $n+1$ is divisible by $2\cdot 3$ , $n+2$ is divisible by $5\cdot 7$ , $n+3$ is divisible by $11\cdot 13$ and so on, so none of the numbers can be a prime power.

Comment: The existence of such a number is guaranteed by the chinese remainde theorem and we can also make this number as large as we wish.

Comment: @Emily.d One minor point is you use $t$ as the number of consecutive non-prime power integers, but also use it as an exponent, i.e., "... such that $q=p^t$ ...". I suggest that, to help avoid possible confusion, you should use a different variable there instead.

Answer (score 0):

As [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s question comments indicate, one way to solve this is to use modular equations and the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). You don't actually need to solve the specific given example, apart from it helping you to understand the concept. As for solving it, though, a somewhat easier example to use instead is

$$n \equiv 0 \pmod{2 \times 3} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$n \equiv -1 \pmod{5 \times 7} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The first one shows $n$ is a multiple of $6$. With the second one, a fairly easy way to solve it is to note the first positive value is $34 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$, and you want to add an integral multiple of $35 \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$ to get $n$, with $6 \mid n$. This multiple is $4$, so the result is $n = 34 + 4(35) = 174$. Now, $n = (2)(3)(29)$ and $n + 1 = (5^2)(7)$. In particular, there's at least $2$ prime factors for both $n$ (i.e., $2$ and $3$) and $n + 1$ (i.e., $5$ and $7$).

For the general case, I believe it's a bit easier to start at $-1$ instead of $0$, as lulu suggested. In that case, there would be $t$ equations, where if $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime, then the $j$'th modulus equation, for $1 \le j \le t$, would be

$$n \equiv -j \pmod{p_{2j-1} \times p_{2j}} \implies n + j \equiv 0 \pmod{p_{2j-1} \times p_{2j}} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since all of the moduli are coprime, the Chinese remainder theorem guarantees there exists a unique solution modulo the product of these moduli. Also, $n + j$ has prime factors of $p_{2j-1}$ and $p_{2j}$, so it can't be a power of a prime.

---

For another method, [Piquito](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/219998/piquito)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951884/prove-for-all-t-in-mathbbn-there-are-natural-t-consecutive-number-such-th#comment8149106_3951884) suggested using $n!$. A fairly simple way to use this idea is to consider, for $2 \le k \le t + 1$,

$$n_k = (2t + 2)! + k \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note $k \mid (2t + 2)!$ so, if $k$ has $2$ or more distinct prime factors, then those prime factors will divide $n_k$, so it can't be a power of a prime. If, instead, $k = p^{m}$ for some prime $p$ and integer $m \ge 1$, then we get

$$n_k = p^{m}\left(\frac{(2t + 2)!}{p^{m}} + 1\right) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

For simpler algebra, let

$$f = \frac{(2t + 2)!}{p^{m}} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $2k = 2p^{m} \le 2(t + 1)$, then it's a separate factor from $k$ of $(2t + 2)!$. This means $p^{m} \mid f$, so $p \not\mid f + 1$. Since $f + 1 \gt 1$, it must have prime factors other than $p$, so $n_k$ is also not a prime power in this case either.